# Unable to get all posts from all three table using inner join and custom get post function

Tags: php, html, mysqli, runtime-error, inner-join

I'm unable to get all posts from these three table "posts, categories, users". I got following errors when i tried to load page **index.php**:

> Here are the page structure and code : **index.php**

```
<?php 
include_once('resourses/init.php'); 
$posts = getPosts();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>First Page</title>
  </head>
<body>
 <?php 
    foreach($posts as $post){
 ?>
   <a href=""><?php echo $post['title'];?></a>
 <?php                   
    }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

> Second php file is : **init.php**

```
 <?php
   //error_reporting(0);
   include_once('config.php');    
   include_once('func.php');    
 ?>
```

> Third file of **init.php** -> **config.php**

```
<?php
$config['db_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['db_user'] = 'root';
$config['db_pass'] = 'usbw';
$config['db_name'] = 'cblog';
foreach($config as $key => $value){
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if(!$db){
    echo "Unable to connect due to: ".mysqli_connect_error($db);
}
?>
```

> And last file of **init.php** -> **func.php**

```
<?php
function getPosts(){
$query ="
SELECT posts.id, posts.cat_id, posts.user_id, posts.title, posts.contents,                             posts.date_posted, categories.name, users.name FROM posts 
INNER JOIN categories ON posts.id=categories.id 
INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id 
ORDER BY posts.id DESC";
$runQuery = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery)){
    $posts[] = $row;
}
}
?>
```

> When i browse the **index.php** page it show some errors, plz see
> screenshot mentioned below:

[image: Error occurring]

Comment: don't know if its causing the issue or if its a typo when putting it into here, but you have whitespace in from of the "<?php" declaration in "init.php" which may be causing the error by not including the config and func files

Comment: No it is typo error only here but in my editor it is correct.

Comment: @gavgrif you can see i include both files **config.php** and **func.php** in **index.php** page so i think i don't need to re-include **config.php** in **index.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the errors say, the $db parameter from the init.php is not recognized in the func.php script. Is there a reason for them to be separate, if not put them in one file, it makes sense.

Then in func.php the array $posts[] is not initialized. Do $posts = array();
and then array_push($row);

This should fix the errors.

Comment: thanks @Ivan i got the error, i didn't return any value in function. thanks lot for help me :)